Vertically center on very small page
How do I center text on a very small page?  This works:
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
foo
\vfill
\end{document}

This doesn't:
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=19mm,
  paperwidth=49mm,
  scale=1,
  left=1px,
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
foo
\vfill
\end{document}

Producing a page with the text about 2/3 of the way down:


You need to take account of the page head and foot, perhaps

\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=19mm,
  paperwidth=49mm,
  scale=1,
  left=1px,
  ]{geometry}
\setlength\topskip{18pt}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}
\setlength\footskip{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
foo
\vfill
\end{document}


thanks! always amazed how quick this stack is
